# Flutter Desktop Video Player with CC

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, libvlc

So I am currently using Chewie https://pub.dev/packages/chewie for iOS, Web and Android. It supports CC. As chewie does not support Desktop so I had to use VLC https://pub.dev/packages/dart_vlc but, there is no documentation on how to implement CC.
I found this package https://pub.dev/packages/subtitle_wrapper_package , it only works with Android, Web and iOS. Any recommendations on how to implement CC for desktop?

Comment: what do you mean "it doesn't work for desktop"?

Comment: If you check the links you will notice that Desktop is not supported.

Comment: dart vlc works on destop and supports chromecast. Have you tried the samples?

Comment: I never said it didn't, please read my question again!

Comment: I guess here CC == Closed Caption aka Subtitles

Comment: @SKJ yup, exactly

Answer (score 0):

Closed Caption or subtitle support on dart_vlc plugin is still an open feature request. Currently dart_vlc is one of the known video player packages that has desktop support. You can track this feature request in this [thread](https://github.com/alexmercerind/dart_vlc/issues/9).